# Shifting array to replace removed element

Tags: c++, arrays, shift

I am supposed to get the output 8, 6. But I get 8,9 when this code is run. Why am I getting the out put 8,6 and how can I fix the code to make the output become 8,9.

```
int inputarray[]={9,8,9,9,9,9,6};
int length = 7;
int value = 9;

void arrayShift(int arr[], int length, int value)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<length; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] == value)
            {
                for (int k = i; k<length ; k++)
                    {
                        arr[k] = arr[k+1];
                    }
        arr[length-1] = 0;

            }       
    }
}
```

Comment: @nem Ummm, this is C. That is Java. Your comment is useless. Even if it were C, it's still obviously not what the OP wants.

Comment: Wait, are you expecting 8,6 or 8,9? You ask it both ways

Comment: Use a linked list, which is the logical way of doing what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When shifting array, you may replace first element (containing number equal to `value`) with the same value from other element. In that case, you need to restart iteration on this element again, e.g.:

```
void arrayShift(int arr[], int length, int value)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<length; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] == value)
        {
            for (int k = i; k<length-1 ; k++)
            {
                arr[k] = arr[k+1];
            }

            arr[length-1] = 0;
            i--;   // <-- this
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer looks correct. Additionally, I would recommend decrementing `length` as well, because array elements are reduced & zeros at the end are just padding.

Comment: I'm having trouble calling the function, it keeps on giving me the address of  of an element within the arr. I put cout << arr; after the initial for loop in the void function. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @Andrew I'm unable to understand you. Who gives address? What address? What element? I've added *one* line, the rest is yours - do you know what it does?

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm for shifting is wrong: you fail to adjust `i` on removal. In addition, it is rather inefficient: you can do this in a single loop with two indexes - `r` for reading and `w` for writing. When you see the value you want to keep, adjust both the reading and the writing index. Otherwise, increment only the reading index.

Once the reading index reaches the count, the writing index indicates how many items you have left. You need to return it to the caller somehow, otherwise he wouldn't know where the actual data ends. You can return the new length as the return value of your function, or take `length` as a pointer, and adjust it in place.

```
int arrayShift(int arr[], int length, int value) {
    int r = 0, w = 0;
    for (; r != length ; r++) {
        if (arr[r] != value) {
            arr[w++] = arr[r];
        }
    }
    return w;
}
```

Here is how you call it:

```
int inputarray[]={9,8,9,9,9,9,6};
int length = 7;
int value = 9;
int newLen = arrayShift(inputarray, length, value);
for (int i = 0 ; i != newLen ; i++) {
    printf("%d ", inputarray[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/KJ1Xh3)